# Error with plugin datetimepicker in JQuery with ajax

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I try to do this, disable all dates and enable the dates that i pass with parameters

This code not work

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "url",
})
.success(function(msg) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(msg));
    var disableIni = JSON.parse(msg);

    var disable = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < disableIni.length; i++)
    {
        disable[i] = moment(disableIni[i][0] + "/" + disableIni[i][1] + "/" + disableIni[i][2], "M/DD/YYYY");
        if (i > 5)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(disable);

    var vectorTest = [moment("5/25/2017", "M/DD/YYYY"), moment("5/26/2017", "M/DD/YYYY"), moment("5/27/2017", "M/DD/YYYY")];

    console.log(vectorTest);

    var vector = disable;
    console.log(vector);

    $('#input_from').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'es',
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        enabledDates: $.each(vector, function(i, value) {
            return value;
        })
    });
});
```

But if i change `var vector = disable` for `var vector = vectorTest`, work correctly:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "url",
})
.success(function(msg) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(msg));
    var disableIni = JSON.parse(msg);

    var disable = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < disableIni.length; i++)
    {
        disable[i] = moment(disableIni[i][0] + "/" + disableIni[i][1] + "/" + disableIni[i][2], "M/DD/YYYY");
        if (i > 5)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(disable);

    var vectorTest = [moment("5/25/2017", "M/DD/YYYY"), moment("5/26/2017", "M/DD/YYYY"), moment("5/27/2017", "M/DD/YYYY")];

    console.log(vectorTest);

    var vector = vectorTest;
    console.log(vector);

    $('#input_from').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'es',
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        enabledDates: $.each(vector, function(i, value) {
            return value;
        })
    });
});
```

Its possible to do that i want??

**EDIT**

The ajax response:

[image]

It's an array that contains other array with 3 position. `[0]` => Month, `[1]` => Day, `[2]` => Year

Thanks

Comment: your `msg` variable is string or object? if object then use `msg.data`

Comment: is a string, i try this, but not work @AlivetoDie

Comment: this is the response of `$.ajax GET`: `[2017,4,23],[2017,4,24],[2017,4,25],[2017,4,26],[2017,4,27],[2017,4,28],[2017,4,29],[2017,4,30],[2017,4,31],[2017,5,1],[2017,5,2],[2017,5,3],[2017,5,4],[2017,5,5],[2017,5,6],[2017,5,7],[2017,5,8],[2017,5,9],[2017,5,10],[2017,5,11],[2017,5,12],[2017,5,13],[2017,5,14],[2017,5,15],[2017,5,16],[2017,5,17],[2017,5,18],[2017,5,19],[2017,5,20],[2017,5,21],[2017,5,22],[2017,5,23],[2017,5,24],[2017,5,25],[2017,5,26],[2017,5,27],[2017,5,28],[2017,5,29],[2017,5,30]` @AlivetoDie

Comment: create a variable disableParams = [true,msg], and then use this disable:disableParams

Comment: send it by converting it to json via `json_encode()` and then use `parseJSON()` to use it correctly

Comment: your msg variable should look like this `["2013-03-14","2013-03-15","2013-03-16"]` .. some example http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CxNNh/1/

Comment: @RanjeetSingh thanks, but not work

Comment: @AlivetoDie thanks, but not work

Comment: @BilalAhmed i use other plugin, not the same, not work

Comment: try this msgArr = JSON.parse(msg) and then use msgArr. JSON.parse() will convert string into array

Comment: @iibtisam thansk, but not work

Comment: whats the error now? 
if the above result is a string make it 2d array string by adding tempMsg = "["+msg+"]" and then use JSON.parse(tempMsg) to convert it into 2d array.

Comment: @iibtisam The console not return error, but the calendar not work. If i use that: `disable: [
                true,
                [2017,4,23],[2017,4,24],[2017,4,25],[2017,4,26],[2017,4,27]
            ]` it work correctly

Comment: then try this ------
tempMsg = "["+msg+"]" => it will give you 2d array string ------
then msgArr = JSON.parse(tempMsg) => give you 2d Array i.e [[2017,4,23],[2017,4,24], ...] ------
then dissableArr = msgArr.unshift(true) => give you [ true, [2017,4,23],[2017,4,24], ...] -------
and finally use disable: disableArr

Comment: @iibtisam i put the console's response: `tempMsg` = `["[2017,4,24],[2017,4,25],[2017,4,26],[2017,4,27],[2017,4,28],[2017,4,29],[2017,4,30],[2017,4,31],[2017,5,1],[2017,5,2],[2017,5,3],[2017,5,4],[2017,5,5],[2017,5,6],[2017,5,7],[2017,5,8],[2017,5,9],[2017,5,10],[2017,5,11],[2017,5,12],[2017,5,13],[2017,5,14],[2017,5,15],[2017,5,16],[2017,5,17],[2017,5,18],[2017,5,19],[2017,5,20],[2017,5,21],[2017,5,22],[2017,5,23],[2017,5,24],[2017,5,25],[2017,5,26],[2017,5,27],[2017,5,28],[2017,5,29],[2017,5,30]"]` | `msgArr` = `Array [ "[2017,4,24],[2017,4,25],[2017,4,26]…" ]` | `dissableArr` = 2

Comment: @iibtisam i think that `msgArr.unshift(true)` is not correct, return 2

Comment: Can you use [`success`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) inside `$.ajax` instead  instead of `done`? Please edit the question showing which is the exact result of your ajax call.

Comment: @VincenzoC i edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "url",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response){
    var disable = [];
    for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
      var data = response[i];
      disable.push( moment([ data[2], data[0], data[1] ]) );
    }

    $('#input_from').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'es',
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
      enabledDates: disable
    });
  }
});
```

You can use `success` and `dataType` key of [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Then you can loop your results and build an array of moment objects using [`moment(Array)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/) method and pass it to [`enabledDates`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#enableddates) option of the datetimepicker.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [beforeShowDay](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay), that function takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:

- `[0]`: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
- `[1]` (optional): a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
- `[2]` (optional): popup tooltip for this date

The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is 
displayed.

Please see following:

```js
var availableDates = [[2017,6,1],[2017,6,2],[2017,6,5]];

function available(date) {
  t = [date.getDate(),(date.getMonth()+1),date.getFullYear()];
  var result = $.grep(availableDates, function(v,i) {
    return v[0]===t[2] && v[1]===t[1] && v[2]===t[0];
  }).length > 0;
  return [result];
}

$('#date').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" name="date" id="date" readonly="readonly" size="12" />
```

In the above code you could switch from *enabled/disabled* by modify the boolean condition:

`length > 0` rather than `length == 0`

I hope it helps you, bye.